# How to get timezone database name

Tags: go

I am trying to get the tz database name with Go running on Debian, such as "US/Arizona" but didn't find a way.  I can get timezone abbreviation but it is not what I want.

I searched online and didn't find any clue.

Any idea, folks?

Answer (score 1):

finally I go with the code below

timezone, err := exec.Command("cat", "/etc/timezone").CombinedOutput()

Comment: You really don't need a command to read a file. Use [ioutil.ReadFile](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile), for instance.